Question on curve defined over a surface patch
Question: Show that if $x(s) = \sigma (u,v)$ where $||x'|| =1$ on surface patch $\sigma$ with the first fundamental form $Edu^2 +2Fdudv +Gdv^2$ the geodesic curvature of $x$ is given by
\begin{equation} 
\kappa_g = (u'v'' - v'u'')\sqrt{EG-F^2} + A(u')^3 +B(u')^2v' +Cu'(v')^2 +D(v')^3.
\end{equation}
Where $A,B,C$ and $D$ can be expressed in terms of $E,F$ and $G$ and their derivatives. Also find $A,B,C$ and $D$ when $F=0$
I do not really know where to go from here, or what formula for geodesic curvature works best for this question. So far I know $Edu^2 +2Fdudv +Gdv^2=1$ since $x$ is unit speed and I am trying to use that the geodesic curvature of a unit-speed curve can be given by $\kappa_g = x(s)'' \cdot (\vec{N} \times x'(s))$ and while computing $x'(s)$ is clear here, I am struggling to use the chain rule to define $x''(s), \vec{N}$ and $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ to find the desired equation. Any hints or help is appreciated.

What textbook contains the horrendous phrase "if $x(s)=\sigma(u,v)$"? Anyhow, I've never encountered this formula before and don't find it very appealing, but it's just an unpleasant calculation where you must pay attention to detail. Write $x'(s)=u'(s)\sigma_u(x(s)) + v'(s)\sigma_v(x(s))$ and then use the product rule and chain rule to differentiate again. Edit your post with a lot more details and a specific question if you cannot complete the task.

@TedShifrin This notation is from Pressley's book on differential geometry and I agree with you. Thank you for your response, Indeed I wanted to know whether the aproach you have given is correct since explicitly calculating through chain rule is horrendous but I wanted to make sure it was correct since it is lengthy. The following week my instructor tauught us Christoffel symbols so I know there is an easier way to do it now. Thanks

I don’t know that book, but I’m surprised that a modern text would have this language. One can’t avoid the chain rule — it’s everywhere in differential geometry. If you’re interested in an alternative text to look at, check out my (free) text, linked in my profile. This chain rule kind of stuff appears, for example, on p. 68.

@TedShifrin Apologies for the late response. I realized indeed the direct approach is to use chain rule, and after some pages of calculation, I arrived at the needed expressions, I was only unaware about how to use the differentiation rule for dot product to solve for derivatives of the coefficients in the first fundamental form. Additionally, I wanted to ask if it were possible to talk to you in particular about differential geometry in general, I was following your book in the beginning of my semester, but my teacher moved onto Pressley's notation and characterizations so I switched to that.

Sure, happy to answer or help with specific questions.
